# Google OAuth 2.0 for server-to-server and Youtube private playlists in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

Good Day,
I try to retrieve my private playlists (and related videos) owned by my YouTube channel throught "OAuth 2.0 for server-to-server";
but I see only public elements!
This is my PHP code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . "/my_service_account.json"); 
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setApplicationName("NameOfMyApp");
$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
$accessToken = $token['access_token'];
//---------
$YOUTUBE = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
//---------
$arr_opt = array('channelId' => $MY_CHANNEL_ID );
$arr_playlist = $YOUTUBE->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet,contentDetails',$arr_opt);
var_export($arr_playlist);
```

I get a "correct" object, 
but if my playlists are set on "private" the fields 'modelData' has no item:

```
 'modelData' => 
 array (
   'pageInfo' => 
   array (
     'totalResults' => 0,
     'resultsPerPage' => 5,
   ),
   'items' => 
   array (
   ),
 ),
```

I forgot something?
It's a limit of Youtube API?
It's a bad configuration of my service account through my console.developers.google.com ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you could use [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it). It should fetch for you all data with some more informations.

Also your code could look as follows:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $YOUTUBE->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $YOUTUBE->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
```